# How can the discrete atomic spectrum be observed?

Tags: visible-light, atomic-physics, spectroscopy

My teacher told me that in an atom (assume hydrogen), as soon as the single electron absorbs a photon with the right amount of energy, it jumps up to another energy level, and ***instantly falls back down to the initial one***, releasing a photon with the same wavelength as the one it absorbed.

So, if I place a source of white light, and in front of it a sample of hydrogen, and then a prism, according to what I have read so far, the screen should show an absorption spectrum, but **why would it?**

Since the electrons are falling back down in all the hydrogen atoms almost instantaneously, they should give out the specific wavelengths of light which form the emission spectrum, which, I think, would combine with the previous one (absorption spectrum) to give a continuous spectrum?

**TL;DR: If a sample of hydrogen atoms is excited by white light, why don't the electrons getting excited and coming down instantly give absorption and emission spectrums respectively, which would combine to give a continuous spectrum?**

**NOTE:***I would have the same question regarding emission spectrums, but I assume all the atoms in the discharge tube would be excited (so no room for further absorption and production of an absorption spectrum), which would give out just the emission spectrum of hydrogen.*

Comment: Depends on your experiment. If you measure the emitted plus absorbed light, then what you're saying is approximately correct. But that's not a very interesting experiment to do...

Comment: @EricDavidKramer    How can we decide which light to measure? The screen will show all of them, right? If we didn't know which light was emitted, and which absorbed, how would we figure out what the absorption spectrum of an element is? (Talking about the experiment with just a screen, I don't know if other ways to measure it exist).

Comment: What you are really asking is how a spectrum can actually be observed, not why it is discrete as suggested by the title.

Comment: Ah right, my fault, I'll change the title :)

Comment: I think the answer is much simpler. As I understand the electron will be emitted in any random direction and won't follow exactly the same path towards the screen and won't be observed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer will depend on the exact experimental set-up. In some cases, the answer to this question is that the electron doesn't fall right down and emit an identical photon -- maybe the excitation is from A -> B, but the decay goes through another excited state, like B -> C -> A. In which case you would get two low-energy photons different from the excitation photon.

Let's stick with a simple two-level model, though, and talk about a common type of experiment, roughly the one you describe -- measuring the transmission spectrum. In this experiment, what we're going to pick up is not that the light is changed in any particular way, but that the light is *redirected.* Set up a light source on one side of the sample, and a detector on the other. Then you measure and see a dip in the amount of light transmitted at certain frequencies. (In practice, the light source is probably a tunable laser that does a narrow band of frequencies at a time and you scan through them.) What happened to the excited/emitted photons? They went off -- but in a different direction. The excited atom does not remember what direction the photon came from and does not, generically speaking, emit in that same direction, so we can detect the absorption by the light that got waylaid. In this experiment we'd see that as a "dip in the transmission spectrum."

I believe in this model, if you had measured the full 3D emission of all light, you would indeed see identical in and out.

Comment: Thanks, that really helped :)
So in a simple two-level model (ground and first excited state), if we set up a screen as the detector, we won't see a totally dark region, but a region relatively brighter than the rest, consisting of the light which just passed through the H-sample and the amount which was re-emitted in the same direction?
Continuing this, in a multiple level model (maybe ground, first, and second excited state), I guess the 'gaps' in the spectrum would be relatively even darker than the first case because in some cases, the electrons would also follow a C->B->A path?

Comment: @VanshajVidyan  maybe reading through  this with real experimental effects might help http://www.columbia.edu/~nas2173/Lab7_SpectrumOfTheHydrogenAtomNS.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The question has a few components to its answer.

First, the electrons exist in [orbitals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital) which are well defined regions where each pair of electrons can exist. Only a pair of electrons can exist in each due to Pauli's exclusion principle. Each orbital has associated to it an energy, and this is what gives the energy levels of the spectrum. The electrons can as you say, absorb and emit light to go up and down these energy levels. They do this by absorbing or emitting a photon of light of the correct frequency, as the photons energy is dependent on the lights frequency.

Let's keep things simple and continue your hydrogen thought experiment. So we begin with one electron in the lowest energy level. Now, white light will not cut it, as it contains only the narrow range of frequencies of light in the visible spectrum. In our thought experiment we can consider shining all possible frequencies on the atom. But this causes an issue, as we will send in photons of such a high energy that the atom will be ionised, that is the electron will be given so much energy that it will leave the atom and go on its merry, now free, way.

Ok, so let's say we shine the correct frequency of light on the atom to excite the electron to another energy level. It will then sit in an excited level for a time then decay sending out a photon of a particular frequency. It is true that by exciting the electron with a different frequency photon could result in a different frequency to be emitted.

So this sounds like your continuous spectrum of light absorbed and emitted could work. But the fact is, that even though we can send in different frequencies of light, and get different ones emitted, due to the discrete energy levels of the spectrum, we would find that only a limited (even though perhaps large) number of frequencies will be absorbed or emitted. As this number is limited we will not get a continuous spectrum, there will be gaps of missing frequency and some will be absorbed/emitted more than others.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the question. I'm acknowledging that there are discrete energy levels. My question is, if we shine light of a frequency which is exactly the energy difference between the ground state and energy level 2, the light would be absorbed, which should give an absorption spectrum.
But, since electrons return to the original state almost instantly, won't the hydrogen sample emit the same frequency, which would fill up the gaps in the absorbed spectrum, resulting in a continuous spectrum again?